# validate form required only if option radio is selected with parsleyjs

Tags: jquery, validation, parsley.js

I want to validate a form with [parsleyjs](http://parsleyjs.org/).

My problem is I want to validate a block of  (3 inputs) only if a input radio is selected.

Here is a image:
[image]

By default, no option is selected.
If I choose **option 1**, nothing need . Validation is ok.
If I choose **option 2**, I need to validate 3 fields more (I have the validations working: required) only when the option 2 is selected.

I have been reading the docs but could not find the solution.

**EDIT:**
Solved by myself adding and removing `required` prop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally solved it, by adding `required` prop to each input when **option 2** is selected, and removing `required` prop if **option 1** is selected.

```
// Option 2
$( '#inputId' ).prop( 'required', true );

// Option 1
$( '#inputId' ).prop( 'required', false );
```

Answer (score 1):

A good approach in this case is to toggle the `disabled` attribute of your inputs and use the `excluded` filter to specify `:disabled`